# Asset-Pipeline does not show Background Images in Production?

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I use Grails asset-pipeline and tried to use the following in my CSS:

```
background: url('landing/background1.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
```

It works fine in dev mode but in production there is nothing being set.

Edit:
The image path is `grails-app/assets/images/landing/background1.jpg`

**How can I get the background image with asset-pipeline working correctly in production mode?**

Comment: `background: url('background1.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;` should just work in production if relative path is used for assets.

Comment: The image path is ``grails-app/assets/images/landing/background1.jpg``